# what does this.props.txt do in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am reading the book of 'React Native for iOS Development' to learn react native development without any react.js experience.
Some code confused me for a while, which the one after the comment in:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // why there is this line and what does 'this' in the line stand for?
    var txt = this.props.txt
    return (
            <div>
              <h1>{myProp}</h1>
            </div>
            );
  },
});
React.render(
    <App myProp='Hi from prop' />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

This is the entire js file which will be referenced from a html file in which there is a div tag with id="container" attribute. Nothing more.
Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is an error in this code and the line should be

```
 var myProp = this.props.myProp
```

`this` in this context is a reference to the React component about to be rendered.

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally I get a more clear sight about how does it work after some debugging. So as you mentioned, there is a bug in the snippet and I made the correction as you suggested. Everything just works fine. Except only one question that what is the argument of return function if `this` refers to the React component to be rendered? It should be the React component, isn't it?

Comment: The `return` is not a function but a statement. The parentheses are just for clarity. The `render` function returns a JSX which upon transpiling to javascript gets converted into a bunch of `React.createComponent()` calls

Comment: Oh, what a big misunderstanding about `return` word. Could you please give me some more details about `React.createComponent()` even a link or something else? I have made some google search and looking up through the book. Not much found.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's actually `React.createElement`. Here's some introdution to JSX and how it gets translated to JavaScript code: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html